# trying to divide complex numbers, division by zero

Tags: c, complex-numbers, divide-by-zero

I'm trying the program below to divide complex numbers, it works for complex numbers but not when the denominator is real (i.e, the complex part is zero). Division by zero occurs in this line `ratio = b->r / b->i ;`, when the complex part `b->i` is zero (in the case of a real denominator).

How do I get around this? and why did the programmer do this, instead of the more straightforward rule for [complex division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_%28mathematics%29#Division_of_complex_numbers)

The wikipedia rule seems to be better, and no division by zero error would occur here. Did I miss something? Why did the programmer not use the wikipedia formula??

Thanks

```
/*! @file dcomplex.c
 * \brief Common arithmetic for complex type
 *
 * <pre>
 * -- SuperLU routine (version 2.0) --
 * Univ. of California Berkeley, Xerox Palo Alto Research Center,
 * and Lawrence Berkeley National Lab.
 * November 15, 1997
 *
 * This file defines common arithmetic operations for complex type.
 * </pre>
 */

#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "slu_dcomplex.h"


/*! \brief Complex Division c = a/b */
void z_div(doublecomplex *c, doublecomplex *a, doublecomplex *b)
{
    double ratio, den;
    double abr, abi, cr, ci;

    if( (abr = b->r) < 0.)
        abr = - abr;
    if( (abi = b->i) < 0.)
         abi = - abi;
    if( abr <= abi ) {
        if (abi == 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "z_div.c: division by zero\n");
            exit(-1);
        }   
        ratio = b->r / b->i ;
        den = b->i * (1 + ratio*ratio);
        cr = (a->r*ratio + a->i) / den;
        ci = (a->i*ratio - a->r) / den;
    } else {
        ratio = b->i / b->r ;
        den = b->r * (1 + ratio*ratio);
        cr = (a->r + a->i*ratio) / den;
        ci = (a->i - a->r*ratio) / den;
    }
    c->r = cr;
    c->i = ci;
}
```

Comment: Ask the programmer. Not only that, just use `std::complex`.

Comment: @Gman. Its a C program. See the heading of the comment, its dcomplex.c. Op should remove the c++ tag

Comment: I believe there could be a edge case bug here. Doesn't make sense to be honest seems the programmer wasn't really a mathematician. 
PS I agree with Tom.

Comment: @Tom: Oh, I swear it was C++... (Oh, it was. Read the tags, what was I thinking.)

Comment: It's the SuperLU matrix solver from Berkeley, developed in 1997 I think. I would imagine a bug wouldn't have lasted that long.

Comment: The reason they jumped through these hoops is to avoid overflow (on large numbers), and underflow (on small numbers).  The naive formula you see on Wikipedia is numerically fragile when using floating point arithmetic.  All of the suggestions below which suggest using some other library (such as C++ std::complex or the C99 complex type) are misguided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like the original programmer was ensuring that `ratio` would end up between 0 and 1 (inclusive) probably to ensure that adequate precision was maintained.

A straight forward coding of the algorithm on Wikipedia looks like would have danger of getting some very large divisors.

Also, as far as I can tell, the following test:

```
   if (abi == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "z_div.c: division by zero\n");
        exit(-1);
   }
```

can only be true if both `abi` and `abr` are zero, so you would be in a real divide by zero situation.

(At that point `abi` and `abr` have both been forced to be non-negative, and that code path only gets hit when `(abr <= abi)`).

Perhaps you can post a small test case that shows the divide-by-zero being hit when `r` is non-zero.

Comment: hmm actually I think you are right. These are absolute values, therefore abr has to be zero as well, thus a true divided by zero situation. MIND BLOWN!! (Thanks for pointing it out, I think the problem is solved then)

Comment: Thanks again. The problem must be somewhere else then, back to hunting it down.

Comment: Phew! Last time I made the mistake of trying to answer a question that had to do with floating point (which is nearly always trickier then first glance might indicate), I posted something that was pretty embarrassing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use this library? C99 has a [`complex`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex.h) type.

Comment: I would like to use this library, it's a part of the SuperLU matrix solver package that my professor wants to use

Answer (score -1):

If everyone wrote everything perfectly the first time then my guess is a lot of us would be jobless.

Using another persons code always carries the risk of running into issues like this. For that reason, I'd sugest using something like an [Apache implementation (std::complex)](http://stdcxx.apache.org/doc/stdlibug/20-2.html). Most of their stuff is pretty well kept and vetted.

Comment: `std::complex` is included in the C++ STL. The Apache page only explains its usage.

Comment: Also it seems he wants to use pure C. Then he has to implement it himself or use _Complex if the compiler has C99 support.

Comment: Thank you for the help everyone by the way, I really appreciate it. It's just weird why the programmer went with all these hoops.